# Auto scroll to end of view in Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have a doubt in Scroll view in appcelerator. Let me explain the scenario in brief, i am using 4 view inside a scroll view. Each view contains a text and 2 buttons, Yes and No. When we 1st go to the page, by default 1st view's text and button shows and remaining 3 views are hide. when we click on Yes or No, 2nd view shows and so on.

My issue is that, The text in each views are a bit long. When comes to 2nd or 3rd view the data shows in scroll view but i'll have to scroll down to see the next view. What i need is that, i have to automatically scroll to the next view when we click on each Yes or No buttons. That is, if we click 2nd views Yes or No, We will have to automatically scroll to 3rd View.

Any help or Guidance will be deeply appreciated. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by adding scrolltoBottom function. Here it is,

```
$.scroll_view_container.scrollToBottom();
```

Where $.scroll_view_container is id of scrollview.

I hope it may help somebody of you. Thanks :) :)